# why do arima's predictions grow rapidly and oscillate?

Tags: python, time-series, data-science, statsmodels, arima

I've been trying to use python's ARIMA's library (statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA) to predict time series. I have 44 months for train points and 16 months ahead to predict. The time series looks like this:

[image]

I used stationary test to find d, and acf+pacf to find best p&q.
(p,d,q) = ([1,2,9],1,[1])

The predictions I get are oscillations that grow rapidly and explode:

[image]

This is very odd and doesn't seem to fit the pattern at all. The details of the fitted model are those:

[image]

You can see that sigma2 (the variation of the error terms- epsilon, to my understanding) is very high- so my guess was that the error terms got very high and the rest of the arima equation's terms were insignificant in comparison. the equation is:

Y(t) = -Y(t-1) + Y(t-2) + Y(t-9) + E(t) + E(t-1)

(I didn't include Mu because it doesn't change too much when I do)

So I believe it becomes: Y(t) = E(t) + E(t-1)

Than the predicted Y becomes large and also contributes to the explosion.
I tried to find and print the error terms but i could only find the error terms of the 44-points train.
When I went into the code itself, is seemed like the equation only includes error terms from the train set, and I couldn't understand how E(t) and E(t-1) are involved / created.

Do you believe the error terms cause the explosion?
If so, how can it be avoided?
Thanks!

The code I used:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA, ARIMAResults
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

date_range = pd.date_range('2015-01-01','2019-12-01', freq='MS')
quantity = [ 9, 11, 32,  0,  0,  1,  1, 11,  0,  0,  3,  4, 18, 18,  5, 24,  9,
   19,  7, 19, 23, 19, 12, 23,  8, 27, 20,  7, 25,  4, 27, 36,  3, 53,
   38, 27, 64, 39, 37, 30, 56,  2, 17, 12, 11, 33, 10, 18, 22, 14, 26,
    8, 22, 46, 10, 10, 56, 33, 36, 10]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Quantity':quantity},index=date_range)

df_test = df['2018-09':].copy()
df_train = df[:'2018-08'].copy()

prediction_period = 16
order = ([1,2,9],1,[1])

model_arima = ARIMA(df_train,order=order)
model_arima_fit = model_arima.fit(method = 'statespace')

results = model_arima_fit.get_forecast(steps=prediction_period)
pred = results.predicted_mean
```

Comment: I fail to see how you came up with 9 in AR lags. When I look at 1-diff'ed series' acf/pacf, they suggest either ARIMA(2, 1, 0) or maybe ARIMA(0, 1, 1).

Comment: @MustafaAydın i plotted the pacf graph and took lags for which the corrolation was above the confidence- 1,2 and 9.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a bug in older statsmodels. In statsmodels master, which will become statsmodel 0.12 pretty soon,

```
                                 SARIMAX Results
==================================================================================
Dep. Variable:                   Quantity   No. Observations:                   44
Model:             ARIMA([1, 2, 9], 1, 1)   Log Likelihood                 -32.062
Date:                    Sat, 08 Aug 2020   AIC                             74.124
Time:                            23:28:49   BIC                             82.930
Sample:                        01-01-2015   HQIC                            77.371
                             - 08-01-2018
Covariance Type:                      opg
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ar.L1         -0.4924      0.900     -0.547      0.584      -2.256       1.271
ar.L2          0.1467      1.264      0.116      0.908      -2.331       2.624
ar.L9          0.5921      0.691      0.856      0.392      -0.763       1.947
ma.L1          0.3137      2.104      0.149      0.881      -3.810       4.438
sigma2       176.1492    227.291      0.775      0.438    -269.333     621.632
===================================================================================
Ljung-Box (L1) (Q):                   0.01   Jarque-Bera (JB):                55.56
Prob(Q):                              0.94   Prob(JB):                         0.00
Heteroskedasticity (H):               0.44   Skew:                             0.17
Prob(H) (two-sided):                  0.14   Kurtosis:                         8.56
===================================================================================

Warnings:
[1] Covariance matrix calculated using the outer product of gradients (complex-step).
```

and

```
pred =
2018-09-01    -374.896081
2018-10-01     130.866666
2018-11-01    -707.873478
2018-12-01     388.816304
2019-01-01    -887.436575
2019-02-01     432.944032
2019-03-01    -813.519861
2019-04-01     259.802249
2019-05-01    -548.478481
2019-06-01     -92.398118
2019-07-01    -136.118320
2019-08-01    -544.271043
2019-09-01     299.615365
2019-10-01    -931.444478
2019-11-01     580.321099
2019-12-01   -1082.708818
```

Comment: I see, thanks! Do you know why the outcomes are so drastic? the train's mean&std is 18 and 15 while the pred's mean&std are -251 (odd!) and 553... Again, the only thing that I imagine causing it is the error terms.. question is, how can I see them? couldn't find them anywhere.